# Difference between require and install vs create-project in composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I don't get how the `create-project` works in composer. Lets take [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/installation) as example.

I can install this PHP framework with the following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
```

This command installs the framework for me leaving me with a few folder in the root of my dir:

- app
- bootstrap
- public
- vendor

Plus some files.

But when I simply use the following composer command:

```
composer require laravel/laravel --prefer-dist
composer install
```

Then this only installs the `vendor` folder. No other files and folders are downloaded by composer.

How come? What is so different? How does composer know what other files to get when I use the `create-project laravel/laravel` command and why do I only get the `vendor` folder when I do `require laravel/laravel`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`require` will add a dependency to the `composer.json` file and load it into the `vendor` directory as you have correctly noticed.

`create-project` on the other hand will *clone* the dependency, i.e. **use the dependency as a template** for a new project. Take a look at the repository behind `laravel/laravel`: https://github.com/laravel/laravel

Comment: Thanks. I failed to see this before, but I understand it now. The `laravel/laravel` repo requires `laravel/framework` which in return requires all of its `Illuminate` dependencies. Those `Illuminate` dependencies require all other 3rd party libs. So that's how it eventually is build up through composer (in case someone was interested in this).