# Certain folders and files missing when using composer to install silverstripe?

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe

When I run `$ composer install` in the terminal to install silverstripe using the following `composer.json` file, it does not bring through certain folder/files. E.g it does not bring in the `mysite` folder or `assets` folder and things like the main `.htaccess` file...

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.2.1",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Where as if I run the create project command from the silverstripe website it creates everything

E.g
`$ composer create-project silverstripe/installer /path/to/project 3.2.1`

How can I bring everything in using my `composer.json` file?

Comment: Did you try adding silerstripe/installer to your composer.json...? Though i personally want assets/ and mysite in my git repository, not installable through composer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a StackOverflow answer similar to this: [Difference between require and install vs create-project in composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22944478/difference-between-require-and-install-vs-create-project-in-composer)

The create-project in essence clones the following repository, which has the files and folders you are looking for: 
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-installer

It also has the `composer.json` file and runs the composer install after the cloning has finished.

So that is a base you can start your work on.

Note, you wouldn't want composer install to replace your `.htaccess` as that is something you edit per project (for redirects and things like that).

We have our own fork, of sorts, of the installer that contains our commonly used SilverStripe extensions in the `composer.json` already.

In our "base repo" we have:

- `.htaccess` with samples of various redirects that you should have (forcing www, exceptions for development domains, etc)
- Our own "project" base template that contains loads of helpers
- Our commonly used SilverStripe extensions in the `composer.json`

We start our SilverStripe project by forking the base repository and then cloning that. We then run composer install on it and then start working on the project. We then commit the changes to our forked repository that relates to the project.

Also, in our repository we have vagrant file to start up a dev machine with all the goodies.

Comment: Perfect answer, makes sense now. I am looking at having a similar setup as you for our projects.

Comment: @ifusion You might be interested also in this https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/vagrant-environment. Well be using ansible on our next "skeleton" and that will be based on https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm