# Install Custom laravel Package

Tags: laravel

I have created custom basic Laravel package and i have uploaded it on my github account and also connected github repo to https://packagist.org .

My repository url is https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message.git

I want to install that package from github to new Laravel application on my local server.

I am using Laravel verson 5.5. Below is my `composer.json` code

**Composer.json**

```
 {

 "name": "johnsmithamk/message",

"description": "Sample Package in Vendor folder",
"type": "project",
"license": "0.1",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "email": "testing7672@gmail.com"
    }
],
"minimum-stability": "dev",

"require": {
    "Illuminate/support": "~5"
}, 

"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "test\\message\\": "vendor/test/message/src/"
    }
},

"extra": { 
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "test\\message\\MessageServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

After adding repository to **Packagist** it tells to use this command to install the packages:

> composer create-project johnsmithamk/message

but after running above command i am getting following errors:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                          
  Could not find package johnsmithamk/message with stability stable.  


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

**Could anyone suggest on how to install laravel package from github?**

Please check the `composer.json` code and let me know whether i have made some mistakes or not.

Comment: you mean `composer requre ......`?

Comment: I tried by both methods 
->composer require johnsmithamk/message  and 

->composer create-project johnsmithamk/message
but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

> composer require johnsmithamk/message

instead of

> composer create-project johnsmithamk/message

I have tested your repository to install into my project and it is not showing any of the issue you have mentioned.

`require` includes the package into your already existing project and `create-project` creates a new project as it says.

You could have a look on their differences:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944572/3887342

**Edit:**

Added your package to the project and got some error but that is due to your some codes in your `composer.json` like:

1.Need to remove this vcs type from the composer.json as we will use packagist.

```
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message.git"
        }
    ],
```

Have a look on some popular package's composer.json

> https://github.com/cartalyst/sentinel/blob/2.0/composer.json

2.Uses the dev only and not master branch as there might be only dev branch for now but need to have a look on this.

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

> https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.5/composer.json#L52

My log doesn't show any error.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Platform>composer require johnsmithamk/message

Using version dev-master for johnsmithamk/message
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing johnsmithamk/message (dev-master 319a00d): Cloning 319a00d01b
    Failed to download johnsmithamk/message from source: Failed to clone https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message.git, git was not found, check that it i
s installed and in your PATH env.

'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

    Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing johnsmithamk/message (dev-master 319a00d): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize

Generating optimized class loader
The compiled services file has been removed.
```

Comment: did it install properly into your laravel project..?

can you suggest me what methods do i use properly....?

Comment: I am installing the package and it is not yet complete. but it is not showing that issue you have mentioned

Comment: @John It is not showing any issue. Have a look on the edit

Comment: sir, is it installed on your project or not... ?

Comment: could you add the console log so we could have a look on it

Comment: I am using composer require johnsmithamk/message

and getting following error                         
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                  
  Could not find package johnsmithamk/message at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minimum  
  -stability

Comment: require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...

Comment: @John Have you removed the minimum stability from your composer.json and tried?

Comment: yes, i have removed, you can check my composer.json file 

https://github.com/johnsmithamk/message/blob/master/composer.json

Now i am getting this error:--

 Problem 1
    - The requested package johnsmithamk/message ~3.0 exists as johnsmithamk/message[dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint. 

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.